# Replace HTML on the fly with Javascript/JQuery, the DRY way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dry

I am kind of new with front end development, and one problem I often have is not to repeat myself when generating HTML on the fly with JS/JQuery.

Let's consider a DOM object that has several states. Often, all you want to do with JS is to switch from one state to another. But doing this by calling `html()` on the DOM object makes you write the same HTML code at several different places (and in JS documents). So what's the DRY way of doing this?

Basically, what I would like to do instead, is pre-write in my HTML document a sample DOM for each state (without altering the document structure), and just be able to replace my DOM with the sample for the state I want on the fly.

Comment: How much of this actually has to be done by rewriting the DOM?  one technique for changing the look/feel and attributes of a page in a DRY way is to keep a consistent structure but change the class definititions of the DOM.  This allows you to completely restyle the page.  You can also hide and show elements using .hide() and .show().  This prevents having to write large chunks of code to the DOM.  You're instead selectively restyling and hiding/showing

Comment: Sounds to me like you should leave the DOM generated, and toggle classes to show/hide the relevant parts of the DOM, rather than trying to rebuild the same region every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var state1= $(HTMLRootElement).detach();
$(document.body).append(state2);
```

As long as you don't lose your reference to the state1 variable (otherwise it will be garbage collected) you can just later do this:

```
var state2= $(HTMLRootElement).detach();
$(document.body).append(state1);
```

This way the HTML elements still exists in memory, they are just not present on the DOM tree.

Another way is to simply .hide() and .show() the content in question. Using .detach() you can choose to append the element of the state you want in another place of your webpage, instead of having it fixed (like inside another div).

Answer (score 0):

There are different kind of template engines in javascript. To name a few mustache.js, underscore.js has templating and also jquery sort of has templating (but the jQuery version never got past beta).

When doing more complex stuff with javascript you can also consider using a framework like backbone.js, sammy.js or knockout.js (there are many more). These frameworks also make heavy use of templates (they use the ones mentionend above).

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options available:

For simple objects, you can get away with creating a variable for each state's HTML, and then using the .wrap() function, chained with .append() or .html() to update the DOM.

For more complex DOM objects or interactions, use a JS templating system: either jquery templates ( http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/ ) or handlebars ( http://handlebarsjs.com/ ). I strongly recommend the latter, as the helpers make it very powerful.